# Same month cumulative sum

Tags: python, pandas, cumulative-sum

What is the best way to have a cumulative total of data values when the "month" in the date column is the same? Can this be done using resample() + sum()?

I'm thinking I can probably use something off the shelf in python instead of creating a custom function.

Want:

```
Input:
             Value 
Date                   
2015-01-01   1 
2014-01-01   2
2017-03-01   3 
2015-04-01   4 
2016-03-01   5 

Output:
             Value 
Month                   
January      3 
March        8
April        4
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case , this can help you out

```
out = df.groupby(df.index.strftime('%b')).sum()
```

output:

```
      Value
Date       
Apr       4
Jan       3
Mar       8
```

Comment: You need to ensure `datetime` type, and this should be `%B`, not `%b`, that said nice one ;)

Answer (score 4):

I would prefer a more straightforward approach with `index.month_name`:

```
df.groupby(df.index.month_name()).sum()
```